# I want the questions presented to me under Questions tab to be "relevant" by default

Tags: feature-request

Use the corpus of my questions, answers, comments, tags etc to figure out what I may know and ask me the right questions.

Edit: Original title was I want a tab "questions SO thinks you can answer"... and a pony

Comment: +1 we need more robotic functionality on SO. Would totally enjoy not even having to look for all the jquery questions saying `givezmedacodez`, and then promptly closing them.

Comment: But then none of them would be closed!

Comment: Not comments though, because I comment on a lot of posts asking them for more information for people that actually **will** answer the question

Comment: Couldn't you use favourite tags? Or do you want SE to do some SCIENCE and come up with stuff?

Comment: Doesn't the system already do this to an extent?

Comment: SO already gave me a pony.  Ok a unicorn.  Ok a unicorn dollar.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/

Comment: Jeff wrote: Just use "Unanswered > My tags". The feature is buried. I think a page like this should be where I get after clicking on "Questions". The relevance could also be improved.

Comment: Something like favourite tags ? Oooh maybe it could answer it for you too.